# Copy all files except those that are executable

Tags: shell-script, backup

I have a backup script that copies all the files in my programming directory to an external HDD.

Right now, the output files are called `program.out` and my script is set to ignore them, but I would like to rename them to just `program`.

- How can I remove the extension of each output file? E.g. `file.out` to `file`.
- How would I make my script to ignore the files without an extension?

In case it is needed, here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cp ~/.vimrc /run/media/alex/32GB/lb/ 
cp ~/.bashrc /run/media/alex/32GB/lb/
cp /etc/hosts /run/media/alex/32GB/lb/hosts
#cp ~/.irssi/config /run/media/alex/32GB/lb/irssi/
#rsynv -av if ext4, tvr and --modify-window=1 for fat32
rsync -tvr --modify-window=1 --exclude-from /run/media/alex/32GB/.exclude --progress /home/alex/Documents/* /run/media/alex/32GB/
cp $0 /run/media/alex/32GB/
```